# Combine regex 'or' with stop at first occurence

Tags: regex, r

Conceptually, I want to search for `(a|b)` and get only the first occurrence.  I know this is a lazy/non-greedy application, but can't seem to combine it properly with the `or`.

Moving beyond the conceptual level, which might change things a lot, `a` and `b` are actually longer patterns, but they have been tested separately and work fine.  And I'm using this in `strapply` from package `gsubfn` which intrinsically finds all matches.

I suspect the answer is here in SO somewhere, but it's hard to search on such things.

Details:  I'm trying to find function expressions `var functionName = function(...)` and function declarations `function functionName(...)` and extract the name of the function in `javascript` (parsing the lines with `R`).  `a` is `\\s*([[:alnum:]]*)\\s*=*\\s*function\\s*\\([^d|i]` and `b` is `\\s*function\\s*([[:alnum:]]+)\\s*\\([^d|i]`. They work fine individually.  A single function definition will take one form or the other, so I need to stop searching when I find one.

EDIT: In this string `Here is a string of blah blah blah` I'd like to find only the first 'a' using `(a|b)` or the first 'b' only using `(b|a)`, plus of course whatever regex goodies I am missing.

EDIT 2: A big thanks to all who have looked at this.  The details turn out to be important, so I'm going to post more info.  Here are the test lines I am searching:

```
dput(lines)
c("var activateBrush = function() {", "    function brushed() { // Handles the response to brushing", 
"    var followMouse = function(mX, mY) { // This draws the guides, nothing else", 
".x(function(d) { return xContour(d.x); })", ".x(function(i) { return xContour(d.x); })"
)
```

Here are the two patterns I want to use, and how I use them individually.

```
fnPat1 <- "\\s*function\\s*([[:alnum:]]+)\\s*\\([^d|i]" # conveniently drops 'var'
fnNames <- unlist(strapply(pattern = fnPat1, replacement = paste0, X = lines))
fnPat2 <- "\\s*([[:alnum:]]*)\\s*=*\\s*function\\s*\\([^d|i]" # conveniently drops 'var'
fnNames <- unlist(strapply(pattern = fnPat2, replacement = paste0, X = lines))
```

They return, in order:

```
[1] "brushed" "brushed"
[1] "activateBrush" "followMouse"   "activateBrush" "followMouse"
```

What I want to do is use both of these patterns at the same time.  What I tried was

```
fnPat3 <- paste("((", fnPat1, ")|(", fnPat2, "))") # which is (a|b) of the orig. question
```

But that returns

```
[1] " activateBrush = function() " "    function brushed() "
```

What I want is a vector of all the function names, namely `c("brushed", "activateBrush", "followMouse")` Duplicates are fine, I can call `unique`.

Maybe this is clearer now, maybe someone sees an entirely different approach.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: The matched string is going to be a back reference in `strapply`.  So when I say find the first 'a', it's going to in parens: `(a)` so that it is taken as a back reference.  In `\\s*([[:alnum:]]*)\\s*=*\\s*function\\s*\\([^d|i]` I'm going to extract `([[:alnum:]]*)` as a back reference.  I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me this would be alot easier combining the expressions ...

```
strapply(lines, '(?:var|function)\\s*([[:alnum:]]+)', simplify = c)
# [1] "activateBrush" "brushed"       "followMouse"
```

`(?: ... )` is a [Non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). By placing `?:` inside you specify that the group is not to be captured, but to group things. Saying, *group but do not capture* "var" or "function" then **capture** the word characters that follow.

Comment: Thanks, I almost fainted since it is so simple.  But alas, it doesn't quite work in my actual situation, where 'a' and 'b' are actually longer strings. I'm going to edit the question with fuller details.  Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Holy Smokes!  Obviously my regex skills are lame.  Can you put `(?:var|function)` into words, as far as what it does?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!  I'm going to inhale this very useful information ;-)

Comment: Quick clarification - `(?:var|function)` means don't capture, but do search for those words, or is it do `\\s*([[:alnum:]]+)`, and then remove var and function if they were found in the results?

Comment: Correct, the first .... I would take a look at the structure of how groupings work. http://www.regularexpressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: Note that one can do it without the non-capturing group like this: `strapply(lines, '(var|function)\\s*([[:alnum:]]+)', ~ ..2, simplify = c)`  .   The formula is just a short form for writing `function(...) ..2` to pick off the 2nd capture group.  `function(x, y, ...) y` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

To match the first `a` or `b`,

```
> x <- "Here is a string of blah blah blah"
> m <- regexpr("[ab]", x)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "a"
> x <- "Here b is a string of blah blah blah"
> m <- regexpr("[ab]", x)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "b"
```

Check the regex with `sub` function whether the regex matches the first `a`,`b` or not. In the below , using sub function i just replaced first `a` or `b` with `***`. We use the advantage of `sub` function here, ie it won't do a global replacement. It only replace the first occurance of the characters which matches the given pattern or regex.

```
> x <- "Here is a string of blah blah blah"
> sub("[ab]", "***", x)
[1] "Here is *** string of blah blah blah"
> x <- "Here b is a string of blah blah blah"
> sub("[ab]", "***", x)
[1] "Here *** is a string of blah blah blah"
```

We could use `gregexpr` or `gsub` functions also.

```
> x <- "Here is a string of blah blah blah"
> m <- gregexpr("^[^ab]*\\K[ab]", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "a"
> gsub("^[^ab]*\\K[ab]", "***", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Here is *** string of blah blah blah"
> x <- "Here b is a string of blah blah blah"
> gsub("^[^ab]*\\K[ab]", "***", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Here *** is a string of blah blah blah"
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[^ab]*`, negated character class which matches any character but not of `a` or `b` zero or more times. We don't use `[^ab]+` because there is a chance of `a` or `b` would be present at the start of the line.
- `\K` discards the previously matched characters. ie, it removes all the characters which are matched by `[^ab]*` regex from printing.
- `[ab]` Now it matches the following `a` or `b`

Comment: Thank you Avinash.  I'm going to study your suggestion.  The last example where you are using `gsub` has potential to be integrated in the `strapply` approach I need.

Comment: Can you walk me through `gregexpr("^[^ab]*\\K[ab]", x, perl=TRUE)`?  My regex skills are limited.  `^[^ab]` means find the beggining of a line that does not start with a or b (I think), but the `\\K[ab]` magic I don't get, probably because I don't know the perl game.  Thank you.

Comment: Not from me, I'm still trying to absorb it all!

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_extract()` from `stringr` package.

```
str_extract("b a", "a|b")
[1] "b"
str_extract("a b", "a|b")
[1] "a"
str_extract(c("a b", "b a"), "a|b")
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: This might work.  I'm going to experiment which will take a while.  Thank you.